# before_create is not called on model.create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this code:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_paranoid

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :organization
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :organization


    attr_accessible :name, :permalink, :organization_id, :user_id

    validates_length_of :name, :minimum => 4
    validates_presence_of   :permalink
    validates_uniqueness_of :permalink, :case_sensitive => false, :scope => :deleted_at

     
    validates_presence_of :user        
    validates_presence_of :organization

    before_create :generate_permalink

    protected

    def generate_permalink
      binding.pry
      self.permalink = "123456789"
    end    
    
end
```

When I call in ProjectsController#create

```
p = Project.new
p.name = "abcdef"
p.save
```

The app doesn't stop on binding.pry in generate_permalink, and the project is not valid and is not saved because `permalink == nil`. Why is the generate_permalink method not called?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set `premalink` in `before_validation` callback.
`before_create` callback is called after validation. and here validation fails so your `before_create` callback will never call.

Check callback sequence here
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html